# Determine if process com.android.browser is running

Tags: android

How can I determine if the process `com.android.browser` is running?

Comment: I wonder whats the use of such an operation??

Comment: @fou, i suggest you to choose a meaningful title for your question. (from next time) :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ActivityManager#getRunningAppProcesses()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningAppProcesses%28%29). it will return a `List` of [`RunningAppProcessInfo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.html). You can check the `processName` of each element in the list to see if it's the process you're looking for.

```
boolean isNamedProcessRunning(String processName)
{
    if (processName == null) return false;

    ActivityManager manager = 
        (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningProcessInfo> processes = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();

    for (RunningProcessInfo process : processes)
    {
        if (processName.equals(process.processName)))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: thx, but do you know the default name of the process browser? and how can I run the browser withouht close the application?

Comment: @Matt Ball, i think, it should be RunningAppProcessInfo insead of RunningProcessInfo .

Answer (score 0):

I can think of the following:

1. use the HashKey to get a reference to the object instance.
2. Use a memory analyzer tool (such as Java Monitor or JMAP) to see the objects instantiated in memory
3. Use JDK to get a Java Heap dump and analyse the results.
4. Add something in your own application to log whenever an object is instantiated or destroyed.

PS. Kind of strange question. Could you tell more on why you need this?

Comment: I guess I misunderstood the question, was thinking more in lines of java objects in memory and instantiated classes

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code:

```
public static boolean isThisProcessRunning(Context context, String processName) {
    if (processName == null){
        return false;
    }
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> processes = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    for (RunningAppProcessInfo process : processes) {
        if (processName.equals(process.processName)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```